# Unsure how to refer to elements in tuples in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to complete a beginner assignment that entails referencing elements in tuples in a list that uses for loops and conditionals to output one of two types of strings depending on the values in the tuples.

> Using a for loop and an if statement, go through vacc_counties and print out a message for those counties that have a higher than 30% vaccination rate.
>
> Add another loop that prints out a message for every county, but prints different messages if the rate is above or below 30.
>
> Example:
> `Benton County is doing ok, with a rate of 41.4%`
> `Fulton County is doing less ok, with a rate of 22.1%`

Here is the list of tuples followed by my own code:

```
vacc_counties = [('Pulaski', 42.7), ('Benton', 41.4), ('Fulton', 22.1), ('Miller', 9.6),
                 ('Mississippi', 29.4), ('Scotty County', 28.1)]

for tuple in vacc_counties:
    for element in tuple:
        if [1] < 30:
            print(f"{vacc_counties[0]}is doing ok, with a rate of" [1]"%")
        else [1] n > 30:
            print(f"{vacc_counties[0]}is doing ok, with a rate of" [1]"%")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remarks:

- don't use reserved words for variable names, e.g. use `tpl` rather than `tuple`
- remove the `for element in tuple:` loop
- to access second element of tuple, use `tpl[1]` instead of `[1]`
- use `elif` instead `else`

Corrected code:

```py
vacc_counties = [
    ("Pulaski", 42.7),
    ("Benton", 41.4),
    ("Fulton", 22.1),
    ("Miller", 9.6),
    ("Mississippi", 29.4),
    ("Scotty County", 28.1),
]

for tpl in vacc_counties:
    if tpl[1] < 30:
        print(f"{tpl[0]} is doing less ok, with a rate of {tpl[1]}%")
    elif tpl[1] >= 30:
        print(f"{tpl[0]} is doing ok, with a rate of {tpl[1]}%")
```

Prints:

```
Pulaski is doing ok, with a rate of 42.7%
Benton is doing ok, with a rate of 41.4%
Fulton is doing less ok, with a rate of 22.1%
Miller is doing less ok, with a rate of 9.6%
Mississippi is doing less ok, with a rate of 29.4%
Scotty County is doing less ok, with a rate of 28.1%
```

Answer (score 1):

You can let Python unpack the two values in each tuple into easy to use variables like this:

```
vacc_counties = [('Pulaski', 42.7), ('Benton', 41.4), ('Fulton', 22.1), ('Miller', 9.6),
                 ('Mississippi', 29.4), ('Scotty County', 28.1)]

for county, rate in vacc_counties:
    if int(rate) > 30:
        print(f"{county} has a higher that 30% vaccination rate")

print()
for county, rate in vacc_counties:
    if int(rate) > 30:
        print(f"{county} is doing ok, with a rate of {rate}%")
    else:
        print(f"{county} is doing less ok, with a rate of {rate}%")
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well, too. So, after "for" and before "in," when you write "county, rate" that is telling Python to make variables by those names in reference to the order of the information in the tuples to place that information for use in the conditional statements?

If I wanted to write a for loop to get the mean vaccination rates of those counties, how would you do it? I'm trying to use numpy.mean, mean(), sum()/len(), and I'm yet to get the syntax right. Will continue working on it. 

Thank you again for the help provided.

Comment: Yes, that's basically what's going on. Each element of `vacc_counties` is a tuple and you "unpack" it into multiple variables. Python 2 allows it and the feature was extended as described in [PEP 3132 -- Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) in Python 3. Once it occurs you can use the assigned variables like you could any other (such as in an `if` expression). Offhand I don't think it would be useful in conjunction with numpy which optimizes computations on vectors of values, so accessing them individually by a name isn't relevant.